# Javascript says undefined after reading json server error response sent by cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Below is my AJAX Method which is able to connect to the server:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data.id);
           },
            error: function(message){
                console.log(message.code);
           }
       });
```

Below is the method that i created for cakephp UsersController class that responses to the request:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return new CakeResponse(array('body'=> json_encode(
                                        $this->Auth->user()),'status'=>200));

            } else {
                $reply["code"] = "Invalid username or 
                                  password and please try again";
                return new CakeResponse
                (array('body'=> json_encode($reply),'status'=>500));
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is, I am unable to read the json response when server sends error. The console.log for the snipped below should write "Invalid username or password and please try again" but it says undefine.

```
error: function(message){
                console.log(message.code);
           }
```

However, I am able to read the following:

```
success: function(data){
                console.log(data.id);
           }
```

Comment: "server sends error" you mean when login() php function return an error or when the server return an error? As i understand it, if login() return error this would not fired ajax error handler but still success {the server has respond correctly}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters of your jQuery `error` callback are described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

So the first argument is the `jqXHR` object, described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

So I guess you can read its `responseText` attribute.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var message = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log(message.code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your below code:

```
error: function(message){
      console.log(message.code);
}
```

You will get the error that is send by server not that you are trying to get from your code.
To read the error from the server side. use the below code:

```
error: function(message,err,xtr){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(message)+" "+err+ " " +xtr);
}
```

Comment: This code works but it doesn't convert the response to object.

Comment: @madi you can use `JSON.parse` to convert the response into object.

Comment: Yes. As illustrated by @antoine. Thank you for the quickest response.